# MySQL divide prices by currency rate from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, orders and order_detail.

**ORDERS**

```
        id_order | currency | conversion_rate
--------------------------------------------
        1             1             1
        2             1             1
        3             7             8.523856
        4             1             1
        5             1             1
        6             7             8.457893
        7             1             1
```

**ORDER_DETAIL**

```
        id_order | id_order_detail | price
--------------------------------------------
        1             1             100
        1             2             150
        2             3             150
        3             4             2500
        3             5             2100
        4             6             160
        5             7             190
        6             8             2300
        6             9             1500
        7             10             125
```

I need to divide all the `prices` in `order_detail table` with the `conversion_rate` from orders table with the corresponding `order_id` where the currency is not 1 and the rate is not 1 (basically convert all the orders to default currency, 1).

So the desired outcome would be:

**ORDER_DETAIL**

```
        id_order | id_order_detail | price
--------------------------------------------
        1             1             100
        1             2             150
        2             3             150
        3             4             293.29449
        3             5             246.367371
        4             6             160
        5             7             190
        6             8             271.93533
        6             9             177.349134
        7             10             125
```

I did a query:

```
UPDATE order_detail
SET price = price/orders.conversion_rate
WHERE orders.id_order = order_detail.id_order 
      AND orders.conversion_rate != 1 
      AND orders.currency != 1;
```

I am stuck here now because it gives errors about unknown column orders.conversion_rate, although it is right there.

Please help me to complete this query.

Comment: Can you write a SELECT that returns the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing correlate both table in your query so you cannot grab data from order table. I used `LEFT JOIN` in my INNER JOIN query to update your orders_detail table

```
UPDATE order_detail a
LEFT JOIN orders b
ON a.id_order = b.id_order
SET a.price = a.price/b.conversion_rate
WHERE a.id_order = b.id_order AND b.conversion_rate != 1 AND b.currency != 1;
```

Comment: The OUTER JOIN seems unnecessary, as does the part about not equalling 1

Comment: Great! Works perfectly! Thank you very much indeed, saved me hours of handwork!

Comment: @popkutt you welcome dude, don't forget to accept answer to help people in the future with similar problems